# create window in tab c++

Tags: c++, tabs, window

I create tab with createwindow. I have 2 tab item and I want to create some static window in 2 tab item. I have use createwindow with parent is the handle to tab. But the child window is present in both tab1 and tab2. I want 2 tab item have a different content. So How can I do that.

Is there another way to create a Static control belong to the specific tab1 or tab 2 ...
Not hwnd of tab from create window. I don't know how to do that so this is my solution

I use win api

Thanks

Here some of my code

```
TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab,0,&tcitem);
TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab,1,&tcitem);    
hwndTab_1_1_1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON",L"sample",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,0,29,100,50,hwndTab,(HMENU)4,hInstance,NULL);
        hwndTab_1_2_1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON",L"sample2",WS_CHILD|BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,20,80,100,50,hwndTab,(HMENU)4,hInstance,NULL);
```

and I'm using this:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TCN_SELCHANGE) {
        switch(TabCtrl_GetCurSel(hwndTab)) {
            case 0:
                ShowWindow(hwndTab_1_1_1,SW_SHOW);

                ShowWindow(hwndTab_1_2_1,SW_HIDE);
                break;

            case 1: //
                ShowWindow(hwndTab_1_1_1,SW_HIDE);

                ShowWindow(hwndTab_1_2_1,SW_SHOW);
                break;
            default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
       }

   }
   else {
       return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
   }
   break;
```

I need the code to the same thing with these code. I don't want to use to much show and hide too many time if we have many child window.

Comment: Moar info. Screenshots. What api you are using. Improve the spelling.

Comment: If it's a standard Win32 tab control then you have to emulate different tabs yourself. You might want to look at modeless property sheets to get Win32 to do some of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: There some of my code. And I need a better way to do that. I see some property sheets suggestion but I don't know how to use it

Comment: You have to make Button Controls look like Tabs

Comment: What do you mean "Make a button look like tab". My problem is if i use show and hide the code will be very long if i have a lot of window. I need the different code to do that. It will be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

assume you have 3 tab pages.

T *pTabPage[3];  point to your 3 tab pages;

int nCurrentPage;   to save your current tab page.

and when you want to change the tab page,

1.hide the "current page" that saved in the nCurrentPage: ShowWindow(pTabPage[nCurrentPage], SW_HIDE);

2.Get the really current page: nCurrentPage = GetCurSelect();

3.Show the really current page: ShowWindow(pTabPage[nCurrentPage], SW_SHOW);

the code is incorrect, just to explain the method

Hope to help you!

Comment: Sorry I cann't understand what you are talking about "T *pTabPage[3]; point to your 3 tab pages;" Can you give me a simple tab code with the static window in 3 different tab page.